# Cannot give limits to preg_match

Tags: php

I just want to make a function to check a string and I want to tell minimum and maximum number  of characters.

```
function check_strict_name($str, $fieldname, $min, $max) {
    $field_errors = array();
    if (preg_match('%^[A-Za-z\.\'\-]{$min, $max}$%', stripslashes(trim($str)))) {
    } else {
        $field_errors[] = $fieldname;
        $field_errors[] = "Info not accepted"; 
    }    
    return $field_errors;   
}
```

If I replace `{$min, $max}` with `{2, 25}` it works fine but I want to be able to tell these numbers when I call the function. I think I understand why it is not working, because the $-sign ends the expression, but I don't know how to replace the `{$min, $max}` with something that does work.

Comment: If you want to embed a variable into a string, [the string needs to be in double quotes or heredoc expression](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), or the variable needs to be concatenated with a string literal. Try `'%^[A-Za-z\.\'\-]{' . $min . ',' . $max . '}$%'`.

Comment: I don't know what to say, I just went to get a cup of coffee and coming back I got the answer.

Comment: And the answer was correct! This was my first question here but it is not my last! I was sitting up to 1 am last night trying to find a solution. Thanks Dcoder and Happy New Year /mr 7

Answer (score 1):

Such syntax is not allowed in regular expressions. Try this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z\.\'\-]{' . $min . ',' . $max . '}$/', ...
```

OR

```
if (preg_match(sprintf('/^[A-Za-z\.\'\-]{%d,%d}$/', $min, $max), ...
```